# Cutting Holes with Text

Tags: modifiers

I tried to cut holes on an object using text (turned into mesh) through the boolean modifier but it seems its not making a complete whole. And I was wondering what is the solution or the proper way to do it.

Thanks in advance

Edit: [Blender File](https://pasteall.org/blend/274db1b23f364a348ae4ca7f9f61318c)

[image]

Comment: you can use https://pasteall.org/blend/ to upload your file, please share the link it will give you

Comment: Thanks @moonboots... I have edited my original post and added a link to the file

Comment: once the boolean is done you could simply delete the bottom faces?

Comment: You mean Apply it then delete the bottom faces? I tried that but it messed up the main object. I should look more into it  and see how I can make it cleaner

Comment: I've just done it and it seems to work fine, enable transparency, select the faces in front view and delete

Comment: oh and you first need to first apply the Bevel if you want to make it simpler

Comment: For the text mesh, just "disable in viewport" and "disable in render" using the outliner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boolean Modifier doesn't like non-manifold geometry, and converting text from curves to meshes produces a lot of non-manifold geometry, So I took a somewhat different approach

- Leave the text as a curve.
- Position the text curve above the key cap.
- Go to Top Orthographic View.
- Select the curve.
- Shift select the keycap.
- Enter edit mode.
- Use the Mesh Menu and select *Knife Project*.

This will create edges on the surface of the keycap that match the outline of the text.

[image: Key, in edit mode, showing text]

- Hide the text to make the next part easy,
- Select the faces that you want to become holes,
- delete those faces.

[image: Key with holes for the text.]

Comment: Thank you so much :)